# Wordpress functions variable, cannot access from another file

Tags: php, wordpress, function, variables

I have a wordpress functions file in the themes directory running some code in order to apply custom fields to the Job Manager plugin.

The code runs fine, and everything works in order for example it allows you to enter the data and the data will then be displayed on the front end, however not where I want it to display.

I have tried including this functions file, into another php file where I am designing the look on the front end. However, when including the file the variables are not accessible and even though I am echoing the variable name out, nothing appears?

I have tried using a SESSION but even this doesn't work?

```
function display_job_salary_data() {
global $post;

$salary = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_job_salary', true );
$salary = number_format($salary);

if ( $salary ) {
echo esc_html($salary);
}
}
```

Salary is the variable that I need to access in another php file

Comment: You really need to show us some code. What does the function look like and how are you trying to output the variable? If the variable is inside a function, it won't be accessible outside the function.

Comment: Is there anyway that I could pull it from outside the function, as it is inside a function

Comment: You can return it from the function. Like I said, need to see some code.. .

Comment: I've just updated the question and added in the code that I'm working with

Comment: I posted an answer with an example...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a variable is created inside in a function, it's only accessible within the scope of that function.

If you want to use the value in any other way, the function needs to return the value.

Since your function name starts with `display_`, it wouldn't be very intuitive if it returned something, so I would break it up into two different functions.

**First function gets and returns the salary data:**

```
function get_job_salary_data() {
    global $post;

    $salary = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_job_salary', true );
    $salary = number_format($salary);

    return $salary;
}
```

**The second function outputs the salary data:** *(Just like it did before)*

```
function display_job_salary_data() {
    // Get the salary data from our previous function
    $salary = get_job_salary_data();

    if ( $salary ) {
        echo esc_html($salary);
    }
}
```

Now you can get the salary data where ever (as long as the file with the functions are included):

```
// Get the salary data
$salary = get_job_salary_data();

// ...or just output it, just like before
display_job_salary_data();
```

To read more about variable scopes, I recommend reading PHP's documentation about the subject here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: Thanks for that, it worked! Only problem now, is because of the echo it is now displaying the result twice. One at the top of the page and then one where I actually want it to display, without the echo though it does not display anywhere.

Comment: That can only happen if you either are calling `display_job_salary_data()` twice, or once and then also manually echo the result from `get_job_salary_data()`.

Comment: It's only being called once, so I don't understand why else it is appearing at the top of the page. I've looked at all of the files associated and none of them have the `display_job_salary_data();` other than the one where I actually want it to be able to be displayed